# why does my android freezes to work

Tags: android

sometimes I get these below Logcat messages and the Emulator freezes and I need to close and restart again.

```
02-03 13:22:09.222: D/WindowManager(59): I'm tired mEndcallBehavior=0x2
02-03 13:22:09.332: D/MobileDataStateTracker(59): default Received state=      DISCONNECTED, old= CONNECTED, reason= gprsDetached, apnTypeList= *
02-03 13:22:09.332: D/NetworkStateTracker(59): setDetailed state, old =CONNECTED and new state=DISCONNECTED
02-03 13:22:09.332: D/ConnectivityService(59): ConnectivityChange for mobile: DISCONNECTED/DISCONNECTED
02-03 13:22:09.342: D/ConnectivityService(59): getMobileDataEnabled returning true
02-03 13:22:09.362: D/Tethering(59): Tethering got CONNECTIVITY_ACTION
02-03 13:22:09.362: D/Tethering(59): MasterInitialState.processMessage what=3
02-03 13:22:09.362: E/HierarchicalStateMachine(59): TetherMaster - unhandledMessage:    msg.what=3
02-03 13:22:09.423: D/PowerManagerService(59): ignoring user activity while turning off screen
02-03 13:22:09.502: D/MobileDataStateTracker(59): replacing old mInterfaceName (/dev/omap_csmi_tty1) with /dev/omap_csmi_tty1 for hipri
02-03 13:22:09.512: D/MobileDataStateTracker(59): replacing old mInterfaceName (/dev/omap_csmi_tty1) with /dev/omap_csmi_tty1 for supl
02-03 13:22:09.512: D/MobileDataStateTracker(59): replacing old mInterfaceName (/dev/omap_csmi_tty1) with /dev/omap_csmi_tty1 for mms
02-03 13:22:09.512: D/MobileDataStateTracker(59): default Received state= CONNECTED, old= DISCONNECTED, reason= gprsAttached, apnTypeList= *
02-03 13:22:09.512: D/NetworkStateTracker(59): setDetailed state, old =DISCONNECTED and new state=CONNECTED
02-03 13:22:09.512: D/ConnectivityService(59): ConnectivityChange for mobile: CONNECTED/CONNECTED
02-03 13:22:09.512: V/NetworkStateTracker(59): Setting TCP values: [4094,87380,110208,4096,16384,110208] which comes from [net.tcp.buffersize.umts]
02-03 13:22:09.572: I/GTalkService(162): [ServiceAutoStarter] --- connectivity changed
02-03 13:22:09.572: I/GTalkService(162): [ServiceAutoStarter] --- start GTalk service ---
02-03 13:22:09.622: D/WindowManager(59): I'm tired mEndcallBehavior=0x2
```

Why am  I getting this error, I am not getting any email id's synchronised in android email application.
Looking forward to your reply.
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to create new Virtual Device with different parametes?

Comment: no I have not created a new Virtual Device with different parameters. I am running on the old Virtual Device which I had created long back.thanks.

Comment: Try to create new, and post the results.